# Vısual sensor.camera lenses with a field of view of more than 180 degree

Tags: sensors, cameras, geometry

What kind of camera models can be used for lenses with a field of view of more than 180 degree ?
Is ıt possible if not why?
Are fisheye lenses suitable for this purpose?

Comment: you may be able to adapt a door peephole lens

Comment: You might try searching Google for [360 degree camera diy](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=360+degree+camera+diy&oq=360+degree+camera+DIY&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l3.7966j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). There are several YouTube videos, Instructables, etc. that might give you some inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the alternate approach of [using a parabolic mirror](http://www.360facil.com/eng/360-degree-photo-shot-parabolic-mirror.php).  The advantage clearly bing cost and possibly operating under lower light conditions. The disadvantages include more distortion, seeing the camera in the mirror and larger over all space.

Answer (score 1):

Simple fisheye lens model will cover angles over 180 degrees. [Fisheye lens model](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/d58/group__calib3d__fisheye.html) maps the incident angles into x,y coordinate on the image using a polynomial function. Thus, whatever the fov is, it does not matter, whereas the most common pinhole camera model cannot cover any lens around and over 180. A perfect solution for what you said.